# Why isn't the 'insert' function adding rows using MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, insert, mysql-python

I'm trying to figure out how to use the MySQLdb library in Python (I am novice at best for both of them).

I'm following the code [here](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html), specifically:

```
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS animal")
cursor.execute ("""
   CREATE TABLE animal
   (
     name     CHAR(40),
     category CHAR(40)
   )
 """)
cursor.execute ("""
   INSERT INTO animal (name, category)
   VALUES
     ('snake', 'reptile'),
     ('frog', 'amphibian'),
     ('tuna', 'fish'),
     ('racoon', 'mammal')
 """)
print "Number of rows inserted: %d" % cursor.rowcount
cursor.close ()
conn.close ()
```

I can change this code to create or drop tables, but I can't get it to actually commit the `INSERT`. It returns the `row.count` value as expected (even when I change the value in the table, it changes to what I expect it to be).

Every time I look into the database with PHPMyAdmin there are no inserts made. How do I commit the `INSERT` to the database?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You forget `commit` data changes, autocommit is disabled by default:

```
   cursor.close ()
   conn.commit ()
   conn.close ()
```

Quoting [Writing MySQL Scripts with Python DB-API](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html) documentation:

> "The connection object commit() method commits any outstanding changes
>   in the current transaction to make them permanent in the database. In
>   DB-API, connections begin with autocommit mode disabled, so you must
>   call commit() before disconnecting or changes may be lost."

Comment: Aw man. Thank you. Thats a lesson I won't forget again! Of course, that works. (And I had all the clues in my question! sigh.)

Comment: @JayGattuso, you are right, your question contains the answer: "but I can't get it to actually commit the INSERT"