# Inserting data into MySQL DB using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to insert data to Mysql database using python. Here is my code

```
def insert_db(time_spent):
global user_id
global total_time_spent
user = user_id
project = get_project_id()
timesingle = time_spent
timeall = total_time_spent
#connect to the database
connect_db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='',host='127.0.0.1',database='python_test')
cursor = connect_db.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO time (user_id,project_id,spent_time,total_time) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",(user,project,timesingle,timeall)) # insert new row to table
if cursor.lastrowid:
    print('last insert id', cursor.lastrowid)
else:
    print('last insert id not found')
#close the cursor and database connection
cursor.close()
connect_db.close()
```

The problem is when I execute this function, even 'last insert row id' is showing the id, the data is not inserting to the database. I checked all the variables in this function and they are not empty.

How can I fix this issue

Comment: You forgot to commit.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173073/why-isnt-the-insert-function-adding-rows-using-mysqldb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you modify data in your database you need to commit all the changes with.

```
connect_db.commit();
```

This is to ensure that you only save changes where no errors happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit to marks the end of a successful transaction.

```
connect_db.commit()
```

For further information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you use `connect_db.commit()` after every insert/update or other such statements.